# How to switch to another activity when an option menu is selected

Tags: java, android, xml

I have tried to use intent but unable to work. Every time it stops.
I have made a Settings as a Java File.
And to that "Settings" java file an xml file is linked
I want to switch to that xml file file when option is selected.

"Settings.java"

```
   package com.navigate2;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import com.navigate2.R;

   /**
   * Created by Nathani Aliakbar on 26-12-2015.
   */
   public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
  }
 }
```

"settings.xml"

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".com.navigate2.Settings">

 <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

"MainActivity.java"

```
          package com.navigate2;

   import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
  import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
  import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
  import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
     implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displayView(R.id.fragmentone);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    else
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}

public void displayView(int viewId) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.nav_camara:
            fragment = new One();
            title  = "Import";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            fragment = new Two();
            title = "Gallery";
            break;

        case R.id.nav_slideshow:
            fragment = new One();
            title = "Import";
            break;

        case R.id.nav_manage:
            fragment = new Two();
            title = "Gallery";
            break;

        default:
            fragment= new One();
            title="Import";
                    break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
     @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings:{
     Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Settings.class);
     startActivity(i);
  }
    }
}
```